# $\infty$ in the extended real line versus extended complex plane

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

The complex plane $\mathbb C$ can be extended to include $\infty$ by means of stereographic projection of $S^2$.

Yet, the extended real line $\mathbb R$ contains $\pm \infty$. What I don't understand is that a stereographic projection of $S^1$ to the real line would also give $\infty$ and not $\pm \infty$. So why does the extended real line include $\pm \infty$ when just $\infty$ would appear to be sufficient (by applying the method of stereographic projection)?

I suspect the reason stereographic projection does not 'work' in the case of $\mathbb R$ is because it is an ordered field whilst $\mathbb C$ is not. But how to make this precise?

Comment: Signed $\pm\infty$ make sense on the real line because it has a total order, as you said. The complex plane does not, but the Riemann sphere makes sense for different reasons in complex analysis. Those are different $\infty$ despite using the same symbol.

Comment: I'd like to point out that it would be possible to extend the real line with a stereographic like function to an "extended" real line $\mathbb R \cup\{\infty\}$, that would be homeomorphic to $\mathbb S^1$. And it's possible to find an homeomorphism between a closed interval $[a,b]$ and the extended real line $\mathbb R \cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$ , I don't know if this could help but for sure it does not hurt.

Comment: @AndreaS. Yes, so as mentioned in my question it is indeed possible to extend the real line by stereographic projection. But what I was wondering is why this particular extension is never discussed. And that is probably in $\mathbb R$ it's less useful than in $\mathbb C$ where there is no ordering.

Comment: The extension by stereographic projection is useful (e. g. in the upper complex half-plane model of the hyperbolic plane, its boundary has to be extended precisely this way), so actually it is discussed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the way to answer this question is to place these constructions in a common framework. More specifically, viewing $\mathbb{C} \subset S^2$ as the sphere minus the north pole, viewing $\mathbb{R} \subset S^1$ as the circle minus the north pole, and $\mathbb{R} \subset [-1,1]$ (with $-1,1$ replaced with the symbols $-\infty, \infty$) are all examples of the same mathematical idea of *compactification*. In general, a compactification of a space $X$ (like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) is an embedding of $X$ inside a compact space $Y$ (like $S^2$ or $[-1, 1]$) so that the closure of $X$ is all of $Y$.

Answering your specific question: the embedding of $\mathbb{R}$ into $S^1$ by stereographic projection gives all of $S^1$ except the point at the top. The compactification in $[-\infty, \infty]$ is taken by embedding $\mathbb{R}$ into a *different* space, which has image that misses two points. They're just different constructions. Your question gets at the question: why would we choose one compactification over another?

The point of compactifications is that compactness of $Y$ (if $Y$ is a metric space) makes it so that any sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence in $Y$. You can then study general sequences in $X$ in terms of their limit points in $Y$. A theme is that the larger $Y$ is, the more structure you learn about sequences in $X$ from their convergent subsequences in $Y$. Folks like to use compactifications that capture structure they care about in $X$.

For instance, convergence in $[-\infty, \infty]$ reflects the *ordering* of $\mathbb{R}$, unlike inside of $S^1$, and $S^2$ has the structure of a complex manifold that is compatible with the complex structure of $\mathbb{C}$ that makes it optimal as a compactification most of the time while thinking about the complex geometry of $\mathbb{C}$. There is a zoo of other compactifications you can use: for instance, view $\mathbb{R}$ as embedded inside a topologist's sine curve as the curve minus the line at $x=0$ and the rightmost point. But while convergence in complicated, large compactifications carries more information than the standard ones, it's often difficult to actually make *use* of it. A rule of thumb is that the "best" compactification for a problem is the one that most clearly captures the problem's relevant structure.